# How to reduce the bias in target variable using effect size of explanatory variables?

Tags: estimation, bias, effect-size, predictor

I want to get rating from students about their teacher's pedagogy (target variables) and these variables has many explanatory variables (factors affecting the rating), knowing the effect size of every explanatory variable (effect size of factors affecting rating), with which method can one reduce the bias in rating?

These are solutions I thought about, but I don't think they may be helpful:

1. Regression is used to predict the target variable using explanatory variables, but in my case I want to adjust (or calibrate) the rating that I already had its value!
2. Reverse regression is used to get the values of explanatory variables using an observation about the target variable, but in my case I want to use the effect size of the variables affecting the rating to adjust it and reduce the bias that happen due to the factors that affect students rating!
3. There is also calibration estimators: using auxiliary variables to estimate the mean of the target variable. But it doesn't reduce the bias for every single rating value got from every student. Instead it estimates the MEAN and reduce the bias of non-response if it's the case.

What can I do to reduce the bias of every single rating got from every student using effect size of possible explanatory variable?